# How cast in XML for aggregate functions

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery-sql

In SQL Server 2008.

I need execute a query like that:

```
DECLARE @x AS xml
SET @x=N'<r><c>First Text</c></r><r><c>Other Text</c></r>'
SELECT @x.query('fn:max(r/c)')
```

But return nothing  (apparently because convert xdt:untypedAtomic to numeric)

How to "cast" r/c to varchar?

Something like

```
SELECT @x.query('fn:max(«CAST(r/c «AS varchar(20))»)')
```

Edit:
Using Nodes the function MAX is from T-SQL no fn:max function
In this code:

```
DECLARE @x xml;
SET @x = '';
SELECT @x.query('fn:max((1, 2))');
SELECT @x.query('fn:max(("First Text", "Other Text"))');
```

both query return expected: 2 and "Other Text"
fn:max **can** evaluate string expression ad hoc. But the first query dont work.
How to force string arguments to fn:max?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the output your looking for?

Comment: I edit post. I need Max(First Text, Other Text) =Other Text as output of SELECT @x.query('fn:max(r/c)'). With numeric data this query works

Comment: Sorry, I don't think you can achieve what you want - using .nodes() is the only way to go as far as I can see.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DECLARE @x AS xml
    , @val nvarchar(100) = 'Other Text'
SET @x=N'<r><c>First Text</c></r><r><c>Other Text</c></r>'
SELECT @x.query('fn:max(for $r in //r return xs:string ($r))')
```

Answer (score 3):

This will perform the aggregate max function in T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @x AS xml
 SET @x=N'<r><c>First Text</c></r><r><c>Other Text</c></r>'

  SELECT 
  MAX(r.value('.','varchar(25)'))
  FROM @x.nodes('/r/c') r([r])
```

Returns

```
Other Text
```

After your update, I think I better understand your question.  Unfortunately It looks like this may not be doable in MS SQL Server 2008 R2.

```
DECLARE @x AS xml
SET @x=N'<r><c>First Text</c></r><r><c>Other Text</c></r>'
SELECT @x.query('fn:max(xs:string(r/c))')
```

Yields the error:

```
Msg 2365, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
XQuery [query()]: Cannot explicitly convert from 'xdt:untypedAtomic *' to 'xs:string'
```

According to [Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191231.aspx) the type cast is valid, but I haven't been able to find a syntax that will work.

Comment: Sorry but using nodes is not an answer is a workaround. With nodes the MAX function is from T-SQL not XML agregate funtion

Comment: The message is confusing or wrong: Cannot explicitly convert from 'xdt:untypedAtomic *' to 'xs:string'. The real problem is not converting from one type to another. xs:string works fine over ONE VALUE, not over colection. This works: SELECT @x.query('fn:max(xs:string((r/c)[1]))')